# iOS crash log is only partially symbolicated

Tags: objective-c, xcode, crash-reports, symbolicate, symbolicatecrash

Here's the issue. I have the .xarchive with all the DSYMs but for whatever reason using symbolicatecrash or xcode is only converting some of the symbols to lines while leaving other ones unconverted. Any ideas? I'm using xCode 4.3.2 on OS X Lion.

For example, from a crash log from the appstore
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f0e628 _semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d66b1a nanosleep
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d71608 sleep
3   AudioToolbox                    0x362b7abc AudioQueueNew(bool, AudioStreamBasicDescription const*, TCACallback const&, CACallbackTarget const&, unsigned long, OpaqueAudioQueue*)
4   AudioToolbox                    0x362b77da AudioQueueNewOutput
5   AVFoundation                    0x359b718e allocAudioQueue(AVAudioPlayer*, AudioPlayerImpl*)
6   AVFoundation                    0x359b54b4 prepareToPlayQueue(AVAudioPlayer*, AudioPlayerImpl*)
7   AVFoundation                    0x359b5a3c playQueue(AVAudioPlayer*, AudioPlayerImpl*, AudioTimeStamp const*)
8   AVFoundation                    0x359b58d2 -[AVAudioPlayer play]
**9   APP_                              0x00049ffe 0x00049ffe

10  APP_                            0x0004fbfe 0x0004fbfe

11  APP_                            0x00051b9a 0x00051b9a

12  APP_                            0x00016462 0x00016462**
13  Foundation                      0x3704f92c _NSFireDelayedPerform
14  CoreFoundation                  0x3156aa2c _CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
15  CoreFoundation                  0x3156a692 _CFRunLoopDoTimer
16  CoreFoundation                  0x31569268 *CFRunLoopRun + 1200

17  CoreFoundation                  0x314ec49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific

18  CoreFoundation                  0x314ec366 CFRunLoopRunInMode

19  GraphicsServices                0x329c5432 GSEventRunModal

20  UIKit                           0x317f1cce UIApplicationMain

**21  APP***                              0x000032c0 0x000032c0
22  APP_                            0x00003270 0x00003270

Symbolicated:
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f0e628 _semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d66b1a nanosleep + 138
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d71608 sleep + 40
3   AudioToolbox                    0x362b7abc _ZL13AudioQueueNewbPK27AudioStreamBasicDescriptionRK11TCACallbackIPvS3_ERK16CACallbackTargetmPP16OpaqueAudioQueue + 680
4   AudioToolbox                    0x362b77da AudioQueueNewOutput + 126
5   AVFoundation                    0x359b718e _ZL15allocAudioQueueP13AVAudioPlayerP15AudioPlayerImpl + 86
6   AVFoundation                    0x359b54b4 _ZL18prepareToPlayQueueP13AVAudioPlayerP15AudioPlayerImpl + 20
7   AVFoundation                    0x359b5a3c *ZL9playQueueP13AVAudioPlayerP15AudioPlayerImplPK14AudioTimeStamp + 184

8   AVFoundation                    0x359b58d2 -[AVAudioPlayer play] + 162

**9   APP***                              0x00049ffe 0x00049ffe
10  APP_                            0x0004fbfe 0x0004fbfe
11  APP_                            0x00051b9a 0x00051b9a
12  APP_                            0x00016462 -[BackpackSetupViewController scenario] (BackpackSetupViewController.m:167)
13  Foundation                      0x3704f92c _NSFireDelayedPerform + 408
14  CoreFoundation                  0x3156aa2c _CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION_ + 8
15  CoreFoundation                  0x3156a692 _CFRunLoopDoTimer + 358
16  CoreFoundation                  0x31569268 *CFRunLoopRun + 1200

17  CoreFoundation                  0x314ec49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294

18  CoreFoundation                  0x314ec366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98

19  GraphicsServices                0x329c5432 GSEventRunModal + 130

20  UIKit                           0x317f1cce UIApplicationMain + 1074

**21  APP***                              0x000032c0 main (main.m:14)
22  APP_                            0x00003270 0x00003270

Comment: try this http://sourceforge.net/p/umsservices/wiki/Home/ 
if it will not help and you send me the crashlog and the dSYM pair, I'll try to symbolicate for you (just to see where the linked in tool fails)